# SQL: Adding column from table B to table A

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in my database:

http://bildr.no/view/SnIzL1Z2

And I want the following output:

http://bildr.no/view/REFDamZn

I have tried with innerjoins, but then I'm returned way to many rows.

Does someone has a solution for this?

Thx!

Comment: Your question is in one link and answer in another link. Why don't you add them all here for readability...

Comment: please put everything here if you have images you can upload on tackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using INNER JOIN

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.ID,
    A.SurveyID,
    A.PersonID,
    A.Answer,
    B.QuestionID,
    B.Question
FROM TblAnswers A INNER JOIN TblQuestion B
    ON A.QuestionID=B.QuestionID
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, I'm still returned way to many rows when I do this. A lot of double rows also.

Comment: @Tom how about adding a distinct in the select. Please check the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select ta.*,tq.Question
From TblAnswers ta
Inner Join TblQuestion tq
  On ta.QuestionId=tq.QuestionId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Distinct ta.*, tq.* 
from TblAnswers ta,TblQuestions tq 
where ta.QuestionId=tq.QuestionId
```